# Web Forms para MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

Entrei em uma empresa, onde possuímos uma aplicação rodando em Web Forms, e estamos desenvolvendo novas aplicações com Asp.Net MVC.
Porém, me foi solicitado para complementar uma aplicação com Web Forms, usando MVC.
Existe a possibilidade de fazer este tipo de integração? Ou é mais viável refazer a aplicação em MVC?

Lembrando que necessito usar a autenticação do Web forms, caso for integrar ambas soluções.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Existe a possibilidade de fazer este tipo de integração? Ou é mais viável refazer a aplicação em MVC?

Não, porque a arquitetura de tratamento de requisições é completamente diferente.

Reescrever a aplicação pode ser bem oneroso, mas sim, é viável. Cheguei a ser contratado por seis meses por uma empresa para reescrever uma aplicação Web Forms sem camada formal de dados em ASP.NET MVC 5 + Entity Framework.

## Lembrando que necessito usar a autenticação do Web forms, caso for integrar ambas soluções.

A autenticação legada pode ser usada livremente no MVC. [Dei algumas respostas ensinando como fazer vários tipos de autenticação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+membership), aliás.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu já imaginava isto, queria apenas uma segunda opinião, para ter base ao explicar aos meus superiores.

Comment: Você pode argumentar ainda sobre o mecanismo de rotas, a capacidade de uma aplicação MVC responder como JSON (parcialmente REST ou inteiramente, usando Web API), e assim por diante. São tantas as diferenças que não vale a pena gastar tempo investindo no Web Forms.

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida, você comentou sobre "autenticação legada".
usar a mesma autenticação e tal. 
Porém eu não consigo pegar os dados de um usuário logado em uma aplicação Web Forms e "utilizar" a mesma session para logar no sistema em MVC, ou consigo?
P.S: Este que será o ponto essencial que meus superiores abordarão.

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Se a Session for baseada em Cookies, consegue. Ou então baseada em um mecanismo de armazenamento que seja compartilhado entre as duas aplicações.

Comment: Obrigado, vou ver como funciona, para explicar certo.